# How to add routerlink with string interpolation in angular

Tags: angular, http-put

I need to add

```
    router= "/update/id" in my code, where "id" has to be rendered dynamically based on values by *ngFor directive. (i.e) {{obj.id}}.So that id gets rendered dynamically
```

How to do this?

Comment: Smth like `[routerLink]="'/update/' + obj.id"`?

Comment: not just "id", {{obj.id}}

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can either use String Interpolation

```
routerLink="/update/{{obj.id}}"
```

or Attribute Binding Syntax:

```
[routerLink]="'/update/' + obj.id"
```

or as Pankaj suggested, Attribute Binding Syntax like this:

```
[routerLink]="['/update', obj.id]"
```

Comment: routerLink="/update/{{obj.id}}" is not working and showing error in my case

Comment: I think your last example has an additional single quote.

Comment: Updated! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Component changes:**

```
<a routerLink="/blog/{{blog.id}}">{{blog.title}}</a>
```

**Module changes:**

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
imports: [
  RouterModule
]
```

If your component reside inside the feature module, you should also add the import and imports changes into the feature module

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
[routerLink]="['/update', obj.id]"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
routerLink="{{objProperty}}/user/help"
```

Working with Angular 7